# Local .xml file converted to JSON with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, xml, node.js, web-services

I'm working in a node JS REST service. All the endpoints are almost done.
I have created a simple web page where the user can introduce a .gpx file (xml) and with the module xml2json convert it into json format. 
I have tried the function using a local path and works, but my problem comes when I deploy the application into a web service, Javascript can not take the local file path to convert the file and store the JSON into the database.
I don't know how to proceed. Should I upload the file into my server and after that take the server path and converse the file? ( I don´t need the file so should I delete after the conversion?)
Could I converse the file without upload to the server?
Help me please with some clues to proceed.
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: this helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/convert-xml-to-json-and-back-using-javascript

Comment: The main problem right now is how to handle the conversion. Should I upload the file to the server and do it in the server side? or there is any posibility to take the path from the user and convert it directly in the client side and save the JSON in the database?

Comment: PHP: use file_get_content to get content of a file, then convert XML to JSON

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936907/letting-user-open-an-xml-file-on-client-and-parse-it-using-javascript here I could find some info related with my problem.

Comment: i get, now try with <input type="file"/> use AJAX to send to file.php then  respond to DOM. finally convert it . this way you not have to save that

Comment: Thank you, I try that :)