# Javascript SyntaxError: illegal character in addEventListener line

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have following simple code (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14147818/5233188)) and Firefox 49.0.1 says it has a Syntax Error in the last javascript line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
    function doit(e) {
        var eventType = e.type;
        console.log("hello");
      var files = e.target.files;
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function() {
        var parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(this.result, "text/xml");
        console.log(parsed);
      };
      reader.readAsText(files[0]);
    }

    document.getElementById("selectfile").addEventListener("change", doit, false);​ // Syntax Error here.
</script>

<input type="file" id="selectfile" />
</body>
</html>
```

Picture:
[image]

I really don´t have a clue whats wrong. I appreciate your help.

Comment: check that that's not some invisible/unprintable char on that line, or the lines before.

Comment: After  the `;` on that line, there's a U+200B character you can't see. Put your cursor on that `;`, delete it and the spaces and `//` after it, then type them back in. (I used to see this a lot on JSBin, perhaps you were using JSBin?)

Comment: You can just delete the question, it's not going to be useful to others in the future. *(Well, you can't directly anymore, someone answered and it got upvoted. But you can flag and ask a moderator to.)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You get a penalty if you delete a question within 30 days.

Comment: @Bálint: Isolated examples are fine. It's repeated ask-and-delete that's an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the illegal character `U+200B` after the semicolon on that line. It's a whitespace character, so you can't see it. Just backspace/delete it, and then type a normal space.

---

See: [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hppxkqnh/) highlights the bad character.

Comment: This is basically a "typo" question. They get commented and deleted rather than answered.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh ok. Is there precedent for that? Like, a meta post or something for how to approach it in the future/now?

Comment: Somewhere on meta, yeah, this was established years back. :-)

Comment: Not a "bad," just something you didn't know. :-)

Comment: For sure. Well, I'll keep that in mind for the next question like this!